# worker postMessage on DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope

Tags: javascript

In worker, I'm sending normal object (which doesn't include any special objects which can't be cloned) via postMessage. Unfortunately I got this error:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': An object could not be cloned.
```

DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope is root object in worker accessible via self (or this when used outside of object slot).

So, what does it mean? I'm not sending global worker scope, so where's the problem?

EDIT: For future readers with same problem. Just serialize object into JSON and in parent thread do the same, you will get your object and runtime will be happy.